# How can I capture multiple audio buffer using iaudiocaptureclient and sinkwriter?

Tags: audio, ms-media-foundation, wasapi, audio-capture, windows-core-audio

I tried to use `sinkwriter` to capture video and audio at the same time, and it worked, but I could only use one audio source. I would like to capture two or more different audio sources (system loopback and microphone for example).

What I tried was to create multiple `mediaSample`s via `GetBuffer` from each `IAudioCaptureClient` and put them in the `sinkwriter`. This did not work.

The other solution I thought of was to composite the pcm buffers from each `GetBuffer` into a single `mediaSample`, but this was very difficult.

My question is, how can I get the exact same start and duration of the buffer packets when I do a `GetBuffer` on each of the different `IAudioCaptureClient`s?

I realize that the buffer lengths are different due to the difference in bitrate, but if the packets are of the same duration, I should be able to synthesize them.

If there is a better solution than this, please let me know.